# change the dimension of div when zooming on android?

Tags: jquery, android, html, css, zooming

I want to know if it is possible to change margin-left of a div when zooming on android so that the div can align the screen.

The div I want to resize is in the div with style width:100%.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no not really.  The webview blocks this because they want users to be able to zoom, not have users try to zoom in and programmers resize their content instead.  You can block zoom functionality, or use a mobile framework like jquery mobile, sencha touch, or jqmobi, but there is not window.resize style listener.  Sorry.

Comment: But is it possible to change its marign-left during zoom on android?
I did it on iphone but not on android.

Comment: You can look here for some people that are attempting fixes, but I can't say that it will work.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10775